# Batch Scripting: Copy the 10 newest files to another folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to copy the 10 newest files in a folder to another folder and rename them in the process. So dir01 contains file01 file02 file03 file04 and so on... I want to copy the 10 newest files and rename them, so say image-01.jpg, to dir02 and so on. I'm pretty new to batch and was wondering if anyone could help me out? I currently have a script to copy the newest file, but only that one file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use somwthing like this

```
enter #!/bin/bash
for file in "$(ls -t|head -n10)"

do
cp  "$file" new_directory/
echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: I need to use batch to do this, not bash.